# How to make PayPal DoCapture API Call in PayPal Sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have send PayPal DoCapture API call by using following form, is this correct way to make API Call. I’m using PayPal Standard account

```
<form id="paymentForm" action="https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/DoCapture" method="post" name="paypal">         
    <input id="METHOD" name="METHOD" type="hidden" value="DoCapture" />
    <input id="AUTHORIZATIONID" name="AUTHORIZATIONID" type="hidden" value="7M4218491W8104419" />
    <input id="AMT" name="AMT" type="hidden" value="10" />
    <input id="CURRENCYCODE"  name="CURRENCYCODE" type="hidden" value="EUR" />
    <input id="COMPLETETYPE" name="COMPLETETYPE" type="hidden" value="NotComplete" />
    <input id="STOREID" name="STOREID" type="hidden" value="938738701158035" />         
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed with Payment" id="submit2" name="SUBMIT2"/>
</form>
```

It Show internal Error? Same time I don’t about STOREID parameter.. What is this?

Anyone help me to implement DoCapture API call with example.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `STOREID` is an identifier of the merchant store at which the refund is given. This field is required for point-of-sale transactions.

Character length and limitations: 50 single-byte characters

This field is available since version 82.0.

As for your form, the URL that you are using is not correct.  The [DoCapture API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/) request would not be sent to `https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/DoCapture`.  The [DoCapture](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/) would need to be sent to one of the Merchant API endpoints.  Then it depends on if you are using NVP or SOAP, and API Signature or Certificate.  You can find a list of the different endpoints [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/).  Make sure you point to the correct endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I have create PayPal DoCapture API Call in PayPal Sandbox code for CodeIgniter.

```
public function get_execute_docapture($product_id = '', $paypal = '') {

    $serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $serverPort = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $url = dirname('http://' . $serverName . ':' . $serverPort . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $currencyCodeType = "USD";
    $paymentType = 'Authorization';
    $personName = "Balasaheb Bhise" . " " . "Balasaheb Bhise";
    $SHIPTOSTREET = $_REQUEST['SHIPTOSTREET'];
    $SHIPTOCITY = $_REQUEST['SHIPTOCITY'];
    $SHIPTOSTATE = $_REQUEST['SHIPTOSTATE'];
    $SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE = $_REQUEST['SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE'];
    $SHIPTOZIP = $_REQUEST['SHIPTOZIP'];
    $card_name = "";
    $L_NAME0 = 'demo';
    $L_AMT0 = 10;
    $L_QTY0 = 1;
    $L_NAME1 = '';
    $L_AMT1 = 0;
    $L_QTY1 = 0;
    $returnURL = (base_url() . 'product/get_execute_docapture/' . $product_id . 'paypal/');
    $cancelURL = (base_url() . 'product/get_execute_docapture/' . $product_id);
    $itemamt = 0.00;
    $itemamt = $L_QTY0 * $L_AMT0;
    $amt = $itemamt;
    $maxamt = $itemamt;
    $nvpstr = "";

    //  Send transaction id hear
    $AuthorizationId = $transaction_id;
    /*
     * Setting up the Shipping address details
     */
    $shiptoAddress = "&SHIPTONAME=$personName&SHIPTOSTREET=$SHIPTOSTREET&SHIPTOCITY=$SHIPTOCITY&SHIPTOSTATE=$SHIPTOSTATE&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=$SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE&SHIPTOZIP=$SHIPTOZIP";

    $nvpstr = "&ADDRESSOVERRIDE=1$shiptoAddress&L_NAME0=" . $L_NAME0 . "&L_NAME1=" . $L_NAME1 . "&L_AMT0=" . $L_AMT0 . "&L_QTY0=" . $L_QTY0 . "&MAXAMT=" . (string) $maxamt . "&AMT=" . (string) $amt . "&ITEMAMT=" . (string) $itemamt . "&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=4&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=0.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONlABEL1=&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=UPS Air&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=0.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=UPS Ground 7 Days&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Ground&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=false&INSURANCEAMT=0.00&INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=true&CALLBACK=https://www.ppcallback.com/callback.pl&SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&SHIPDISCAMT=0.00&TAXAMT=0.00&L_NUMBER0=1000&L_DESC0=" . $card_name . "&L_NUMBER1=&L_DESC1=&L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE1=&L_ITEMWEIGHTUNIT1=&ReturnUrl=" . $returnURL . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType . "&AUTHORIZATIONID=" . $AuthorizationId . "&COMPLETETYPE=" . "Complete";
    $nvpstr = $nvpHeader . $nvpstr;

    $resArray = hash_call("DoCapture", $nvpstr);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($resArray);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: `hash_call` is PHP Default Function? Can't found that